# Mosaic floor polishing- What to use

Tags: tile, mosaic, polish

I have a mosaic floor which caught mold from rotten food some time ago. Here is the floor which is ok (with and without flash).
[image]
[image]

And here is the damaged floor after the "polishing". I tried to do with diamond polishing pads of grits 400,800.
[image]
[image]
[image]

As you can see the result is no good. The polish is insufficient. Even the bulk imperfections and discoloration from the mold damage haven't been taken out although I have polished thoroughly with good pressure. Should I have tried lower grit than 400,or bring a professional to do the whole room?(I'm trying to do only the part which got damaged)

Answer (score 1):

Your first mistake was using the diamond pads. Part of the discoloration is stone dust being embedded in the concrete filler. You had a mold problem or staining from food/drinks being spilled. You should have started out with a non abrasive concrete / grout cleaner. You could have even used a mixture of beach and water. Try doing this and just work on the cement/grout filling. Once that's cleaned up use a buffing pad and polish on the affected stones.

Comment: I did try mopping with bleach before using the diamond pads but nothing happened. Also had tried vinegar.  Maybe should have used a brush? I will get a grout cleaner and try.

Shall i use Brasso or plastic polish with the buffing wheel?